# Create Intent from Shortcut

Tags: android, xposed

I have installed Xposed and GravityBox Module on Android Oreo.
With Nova Launcher I created an action-shortcut to GravityBox in order to make my device go on Sleep.
I found the Intent in the shortcut-database of Nova Launcher, and the code is:

```
#Intent;action=gravitybox.intent.action.LAUNCH_ACTION;launchFlags=0x10008000;component=com.ceco.oreo.gravitybox/.shortcuts.LaunchActivity;S.action=gravitybox.intent.action.SLEEP;S.actionType=broadcast;end
```

Now I'm writing a small App in Android Studio and I want to use the same Intent in order to PowerOff screen quickly using GravityBox when I press a Button in my App. My button method will be like:

```
public void mPowerOFF(){

   try {

       Intent screenOffIntent = new Intent();
       screenOffIntent.setAction("gravitybox.intent.action.LAUNCH_ACTION");
       screenOffIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       screenOffIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
       screenOffIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.ceco.oreo.gravitybox", "com.ceco.marshmallow.gravitybox.shortcuts.LaunchActivity"));
       screenOffIntent.putExtra("I believe others stuff goes here but I don't know how");
```

I found on a site that the unique `launchflags=0x10008000` will split in 
`screenOffIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 screenOffIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

What I'm missing to complete my job?